# Не работают CSS-стили с PHP

Tags: php, html, css

Есть файл **index.php.** В нем есть код на самом php, а также html код. 
И файл со стилями **style.css** в одной директории что и index.php

**Вот код файла index.php**

```php
<?php
require "db.php";

$registrInfo = $_POST;
if (isset ($registrInfo["otpravka"])) {
    if (trim($registrInfo["loginUser"] == '')) {
        $errors[] = 'Вы не ввели логин!';
    }
    if (trim($registrInfo["passUser"] == '')) {
        $errors[] = 'Вы не ввели пароль!';
    }
    if (trim($registrInfo["nameUser"] == '')) {
        $errors[] = 'Вы не ввели ваше имя!';
    }
    if (empty($errors)) {

    } else {
        $countErrors = count ($errors);
        echo 
        '<html><body><div class="errorsStyle">
            <ul> 
                <li>' . array_shift($errors) . '</li>   
            </ul>
        </div></body></html>';  
    }   
}   
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Авторизация</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="registr">
        <form action="index.php" method="POST" id="userInfo" >
            <label for="login">
                Логин<br><input type="text" name="loginUser" id="login" value="<?php echo $registrInfo["loginUser"];?>" placeholder="Придумайте логин... "><hr> 
            </label>
            <label for="password">
                Пароль<br><input type="password" name="passUser" id="password" value="<?php echo $registrInfo["passUser"];?>" placeholder="Придумайте пароль... "><hr> 
            </label>
            <label for="nameUser">
                Ваше имя<br><input type="text" name="nameUser" id="name" value="<?php echo $registrInfo["nameUser"];?>" placeholder="Введите ваше имя... "><hr> 
            </label>
            <input type="submit" name="otpravka" value="Отправить"><br>     
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

*Код css стилей сбрасывать не буду, но в общем любая манипуляция там игнорируется web - страницей.*

*P.S если что, то файлы лежат на OpenServer в папке domains/test.ru*

Comment: допустим в css единственная строка:
body, html {
   color: red;
}
Ничего не применяется. Вообще. Абсолютный путь тоже не работает

Comment: Причем уже 2 раза было такое, что стили все таки применились...хотя как то не правильно (например, в стилях написано шрифт 20px, а там все 40px получились). Но потом изменяю стили, пытаюсь обновить страницу и все...опять не применяются. Чет вообще не понимаю что происходит

Comment: У него не работают css только в Google Chrome во всех остальных всё отлично... я не знаю почему у него так , очищали КЭШ и даже переустановили Хром .. ситуация не изменилась

Answer (score 2):

Блиан, запрещает оставлять комментарии из за малой репутации. В общем я оформил html как нужно и у меня стили применились...Однако опять же, как только я изменил в стилях шрифт, новый размер шрифта не применился. Так же создал папку `css` и туда положил файл `style.css`
путь теперь прописываю так: `href="/css/style.css"`

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <title>Авторизация</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <meta charset="utf8">

Comment: Я уже всяко разно просто пытался. Один результат: стили после изменений бывает применятся и всё....дальше их форматируй как хочешь, но ничего не изменится. Можете скинуть как вы html оформили?

Comment: нет, сейчас скачаю

Comment: Отключите кэширование, где лежит файл стилей вообще неважно. Когда вы его перемещаете он еще не закэширован

Comment: `ctrl + f`, очистите кэш браузера.

Answer (score 0):

В любых подобных ситуациях следует для начала полностью обновить страницу (<kbd>Ctrl+F5</kbd>, а не просто <kbd>F5</kbd>). Тогда все стили и прочее загрузятся заново даже если они закешированы.

Если не поможет стоит включить в браузере инструменты разработчика (<kbd>F12</kbd> а FireFox и Chrom), перейти на вкладку «Сеть» и, опять же, полностью форсированно обновить страницу (<kbd>Ctrl+F5</kbd>). Посмотрите загружается-ли файл стилей, там-же можно посмотреть его содержимое (возможно, по какой-либо причине оно не соответствует ожиданиям)

Comment: я через team viewer это всё делал , написал же выше , что не работает только в Chrome , во всех остальных браузерах всё работает , то что вы написали всё уже делали

Comment: @МаксимЛенский через тимвьювер нельзя запу4стить инструменты разработчика? Если можно то напиши качает-ли браузер стили. Если да то соответствует-ли их контент ожиданиям. Если нет то какие при этом происходят запросы, есть-ли 404 ошибки, что идёт в консоль браузера? Возможно в Хроме закешировалось что-то не то, а в остальных браузерах — нет.

Comment: работает и dev tools и всё что угодно .. ни чего не происходит , просто не работают стили и всё .. именно в Хром , не ошибки 404 ни чего , х.з почему .. я час этим занимался и так и не понял почему

Comment: @МаксимЛенский телепаты в отпуске. На вопрос виде «у меня ничего не работает» сложно ответить что-то кроме «попробуйте сделать что-нибудь». Что в консоли браузера при полном обновлении страницы? Что на вкладке сетевых запросов? Не можешь словами описать — покажи скриншоты. Посмотри код страницы в браузере, возможно это не та версия страницы в которой подключены CSS стили

Comment: я не топик стартер

Comment: @МаксимЛенский в данные момент вы похоже его заместитель

Comment: пишите ответ ещё один ...

Answer (score 0):

У меня бывало при разработке на локальном сервере что браузер кешировал js и css файлы и изменения не работали. Нашел такой вариант : при подключении файлов дописывать к ним в качестве параметра timestamp. Например

```
<script src="script.js?<?echo time();?>"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?<?echo time();?>">
```

И файлы каждый раз считаются новыми

Answer (score 0):

```
Это очень странно но мне помогло это. Я убрал все точки в начале каждого элемента.
Было

.table {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-collapse: separate;
}

Стало

table {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Мне `Ctrl + F5` помогло при обновлении страницы в браузере, а не просто `F5`.

Answer (score -1):

Стили не применяются из-за того, что старый файл стилей подгружен в кеше вашего компьютера. Перейдите в историю и очистите кэш и подгруженные файлы и папки. В хроме это история, очистить историю и оставьте галочку перед "изобрадения и другие файлы, сохраненные в кеше".