# Объясните в чем проблема css

Tags: html, css

Есть проект с использованием HTML, CSS. При открытии index в Chrome не подружаются все стили, только в инкогнито. В других браузерах все стиле хорошо подружаются. Проблема только с Chrome, так в чем она?

Comment: Больше данных, ничего же не понятно.

Comment: Какие необходимы данные?

Comment: Ну, пример хотя бы. Возможно файл стилей отдается как plain text и хром игнорирует его.

Comment: я вот не давно как раз пробовал решить такую же проблему , не получилось https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/663651/33274

Comment: @lampa я вот ссылку приложил , посмотри по ней , боролся точно так же как и автор этого вопроса ..

Comment: @Максим Ленский тут можно только предполагать, почему так происходит, не имея информации из инструментов разработчика. Понимаете, это как обсуждать, почему не заводится двигатель, не зная причины поломки.

Comment: @lampa я через тем вивер подключался к автору того вопроса , и браузер очищал от кэша , и создавал через define путь до css , и удалял хром и заново скачивал , и путь в дэв тулс отображался , и даже при переходе по ссылке до css он открывался , а вот стили не работали, я взял весь код index.php к себе на localhost скопировал , у меня работало а у автора хоть тресни : нет

Comment: @МаксимЛенский вы же должны понимать, что чудес не бывает. На досуге можно создать чат и выявить корень проблемы

Comment: @lampa я два часа потратил на это .. нет уж с меня хватит .. но мне очень интересно `Решение`

Comment: вы хоть скажите как страницу запускаете? просто с папочки html файл, или ссервер стартует? Если сервер то какой, исли файл то какой путь до файла?