# Проблема с подключением CSS

Tags: html, css, css3

Есть линк с СSS

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style/account-style/style.css"/>
```

Когда я её только подключил, она работает, и в редакторе (Sublime text), когда я изменяю CSS код, она работает. Но через некоторое время, когда я не изменяю css код, она бывает подключенная, но когда я изменяю css код, она не изменяется то есть остается стиль до закрытия редактора. Каждый раз приходиться создавать новый css-файл, копировать старый код и вставлять в новый, и изменять путь css файла.

С:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style/account-style/style.css"/>
```

На:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style/account-style/style2.css"/>
```

Не могу понять в чем проблема.

Comment: Возможно дело в кэше браузера, можно чистить кэш или обновлять страницу через `ctrl+f5`

Comment: проблему не решит но можно не создавать новый файл, а давать версии файлу style.css?v=0.01

Comment: Проверь во всех браузерах... Доступных... Может быть  баг самого браузера.  Недавно обнаружил баг в `opera`, не имеет отношения к  твоей проблеме, но смысл в том, что именно баг браузера... Очисти кеш, как предложил  Sergey Glazirin

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin Проблема была в этом. Спасибо

Comment: @Air Зашел через Mozilla там все работает, Пришлость очистить кэш. Спаибо

Comment: @ruslan4742, кстати для справки. А в каком браузере была проблема?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/779591/202854