# Как принудительно обновить файл JS в кэше браузера пользователя?

Tags: javascript

Когда вношу изменения в JS файл и загружаю на сервер, то, если не обновлять кэш на других компьютерах и устройствах, иногда выдает ошибки, пока не обновит кэш. Есть ли какие то методы, чтобы при внесении изменений принудительно обновить кэш?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Насколько мне известно, наиболее распространенное решение - это добавлять в конец линка скрипта `?<version>`

Например:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js?1500"></script>
```

Я могу предположить, что не самое лучшее решение каждый раз находить и менять версию во всех скриптах. Однако, если вы будете использовать систему контроля версий, то многие имеют возможность автоматически подставлять номер версии на стадии подготовки.

Это будет выглядеть так:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js?$$REVISION$$"></script>
```

Comment: спасибо помогло=)

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел для себя такой выход, 
не нужно думать о версии и писать ее вручную

> У меня бывало при разработке на локальном сервере что браузер кешировал js и css файлы и изменения не работали. Нашел такой вариант : при подключении файлов дописывать к ним в качестве параметра timestamp И файлы каждый раз считаются новыми. Например:

```
<script src="script.js?<?echo time();?>"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?<?echo time();?>">
```

[Источник](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/779591/202854)

Comment: Приведите код из ответа по ссылке в свой ответ.

Comment: Плохой пример, по факту в этом примере кеширование вообще удаляется, и каждый раз при перезагрузке страницы юзер качает новые файлы, независимо от того менялись они или нет